# Show tablix footer of sum at bottom of report body

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, rdlc, microsoft-reporting

I am developing an invoice application using Microsoft Visual Studio 2015, C# with rdlc reports.

I want to print invoice with sold item list, showing total of each column at bottom of body alwasy, regardless of one item or multiple items on the report.

Right now I am facing an issue with rdlc, showing total footer only below last item.

How can I show footer row of tablix alwasy at bottom of body?

### Required output

```
NO            ITEM                  QTY             RATE                TOTAL
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1             SHOES                 2               1500                3000

















--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                                         3000
```

Answer (score 0):

I could add the textboxes in the footer and add a formula to show each total.

```
=Sum(Fields!Total.Value, "DataSetName")
```

This shoud do the work.